# Denominators in a continued fraction

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, continued-fractions

I'm doing some "research" for a high school competition, and I stumbled upon a problem I'll describe below. I'll be thankful for any references where can I find any results on this topic – I can't find anything, but on the other hand I would be very surprised if nobody had ever thought of that.

I have a number $N$, and I want to find such $a \in \{1,2,\ldots,N\}$ that $\gcd(a,N)=1$ and continued fraction of $\frac{a}{N}$ has a

1. minimal sum of denominators (I mean coefficients, I'm not sure of correct terminology in English)

or

2. maximal number of denominators

I'm directly interested only in 1), but 2) would suffice for me for deriving some bounds.

I'm able to prove that the answer to 1) lies between $\log (N)$ and $\sqrt{N}\log (N)$, and I think my method implies that the answer to 2) is between $\frac{1}{2} \log (N) - o(\log (N))$ and $\log (N)$ (to be exact, these logarithms have to have base $\phi$, anyway any improvement of constant here would give much better bounds in 1)).

As I have said, I'm looking if something like this has already been done by someone with broader knowledge than mine. I couldn't find anything similar, but on the other hand I'm not used to doing such searches and I think it's more probable that I wasn't searching well than that nothing was done in this subject.

EDIT: I've just realize that my $O(\sqrt{n} \log(n))$ bound I was so proud of can be trivially replaced by $O(\sqrt{n})$ by taking simply $a \approx \sqrt{N}$ (my former strategy was taking $a \approx \frac{N}{\phi}$, which should work much better in average case, but has worse worst case performance).

Comment: I'm not used to terminology in English, but if our continued fraction is $[a_0;a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k]$, I'm interested in minimal $\sum a_i$, or maximal $k$. (in our case $a_0$ is actually zero, so it doesn't change much)

Comment: Wikipedia suggests term "coefficient", so I'll add that to the post to specify what I mean

Comment: the traditional term for the $a_i$ was partial quotients (in Hardy and Wright). On this site, I just use the word "digits,"   I'm probably the only one; Khinchin calls them "elements" in his little book. Look under the Extended Euclidean Algorithm; finite continued fractions are a way to find the Bezout equation $ Nx -ay = 1$ in integers. Finally, program something and print out $a,N$ when especially long continued fractions show up. When I have no idea what is going on, I mostly have an extra variable, maybe $L$ for this one, every time a length is bigger than the current value of $L,$

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks for comment about terminology! I'm already aware of connection to Euclidean Algorithm (actually I started from that, and then just translated the problem to continued fractions). Programming didn't help much – values seem to be not very different from lower bound, but respective $a$-s seem to be irregular – sometimes they're close to $\frac{N}{\phi+k}$ for some small integers $k$, but it doesn't always work, and it doesn't produce much better lower bounds than I already have (well, actually, again, that was exactly my approach)

Comment: I agree that, for a given $N,$  there is little to tell you what coprime value of $a$ gives the longest fraction. On the other hand, there are values of $N$ that give longer fractions than any smaller $N$ ( for some $a$ which is initially unpredictable). So the "outer" experiment is to find the sequence of increasing $N$ for which the best/longest fraction is longer than previous $N.$       This construction is sometimes called the "champion" numbers. Later you can worry about the particular choice of $a$ for which a champion $N$ achieves its longest fraction.

Comment: the first "champion" number sequences I came across are the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number   and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_abundant_number  I should write a command that just finds the length of the continued fraction for a pair of numbers (a,b)  and just returns the length, without printing anything. Then the "outer" experiment is just to double loop (N,a), with a variable  L for biggest length so far. If a new length L_1 comes up  bigger still,   set L := L_1  and print out L_1, N, a .  I may have a "length " command already.

Comment: I know that such $N$-s are precisely Fibonacci numbers and they're my "champion numbers" (and we can then take $a$ to be previous Fibonacci number), but this is for me somehow "the best case". I'm interested in the worst cases, and they seem more random, for example I haven't found that sequence in OEIS. Paradoxically, these worst cases aren't that bad, and they don't look like they have any particular properties